# Why do some encoding (and other intense processes) run more quickly (using Windows 10) when processor is busy?

Tags: cpu

I've noticed that some computationally intense processes (in the most recent case, using [Shotcut](http://www.shotcut.org) to convert an mp4 file to a gif file) seem to actually use up more of my processor's processing capacity when there are other computationally intense programs running.  These other programs are usually either [BOINC](https://boinc.berkeley.edu) or [Prime95](http://www.mersenne.org), and so they both will tend to cause my computer use its maximum processing capability that have I set (~92%).

When running only the encoding task, Shotcut was consistently using about 25% of my processor, but with Prime95 running, the encoding consistently took up about 33% of my processor.

Why do things seem to be willing to take up more of my processor's clock cycles when there's more competition?  I honestly cannot think of a single plausible explanation for this.

All the numbers are according to Windows 10's task manager, but I have noticed this happening in Windows 8.1 as well.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What Shortcut does and what Prime95 are entirely two different things.  The actual processor instructions ran are entirely different.

Comment: Personally, I think you are chasing a ghost, but use a utility like CoreTemp to watch your CPU frequency scaling. It is possible that shotcut is not causing the system to ramp the CPU frequency up to max, but that when another process on another core does, your process runs at full speed on another core.

Comment: oooh, interesting thought @FrankThomas, that's certainly a more plausible one than I've yet had.

And Ramhound, I'm not saying they're doing anything even remotely similar.  I've just found that there's a definite correlation between Shotcut's processor usage and the overall processor usage.